# WP7 - Element over a webbrowser?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, browser, element

I have a webbrowser element. Buttons and listboxes work fine on top of the webbrowser, but now I wanna add a textblock and use the manipulation started event, but it wont work.
Any solutions for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try increasing the TextBlock's Z-index to a higher number than whatever the WebBrowser's Z-index is (default being 0).

```
<TextBlock Canvas.ZIndex="100" .... />
```

Comment: I freaking love you! Thanks alot!